# How to find duration of an .spx audio file using .NET code

Tags: asp.net, .net

I tried using NAudio and libraries related to it but not able to find anything useful. I have used code below.

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string filePath = "example.spx"; // replace with your file path
var reader = new NAudio.Vorbis.VorbisWaveReader(filePath);
TimeSpan duration = reader.TotalTime;
Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + duration.ToString());
}
}
```